# meteor autoform string array shows empty field

Tags: arrays, meteor, meteor-autoform

I make edit form for some collection, it has Array fields 'phones', each element is String
When I trying to make afArrayField from this field it shows block with one empty string

Schema:

```
    {phones:
        {type: Array,
        minCount: 1,
        label: "Phones numbers"},
    {"phones.$":
        {type: String}
    }
```

Template:

```
    {{> afQuickField name="phones" value=phones}}
```

In object array 'phones' is presented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've the following:

```
  phones: {
    type: [String],
    minCount: 1,
    label: "Phones numbers"
  },
  'phones.$': {
    autoform: {
      afFieldInput: {
        type: 'text'
      }
    }
  }
```

Template helper

```
Template.home.helpers({
  doc: {phones: ['09988765', '0998776']} // this should come from db.findOne
})
```

In template:

```
{{#autoForm id='test' schema="Schema.Array" type="update" doc=doc}}
  {{> afQuickField name="phones" value=doc.phones}}
{{/autoForm}}
```

I'm having this: 
[image: arrayField]

I've the following package dependencies:

```
meteor-platform
standard-app-packages
iron:router
iron:layout
aldeed:collection2
aldeed:simple-schema
aldeed:autoform
nemo64:bootstrap
less
accounts-base
accounts-password
```

Comment: Meteor says:
Error: Invalid definition for phones.$ field

Comment: Oups, and with type: 'text' ?

Comment: ReferenceError: text is not defined

Comment: Do you have the ' around text; type: 'text'

Comment: again  Error: Invalid definition for phones.$ field

Comment: Him, let my take my computer and try this

Comment: Into phones definition, I'm using the following: phones:{ type: [String] } instead of Array

Comment: Maybe something in template is wrong? It seems that data not given

Comment: hum, update form! have you defined a document for update into helpers? shouldn't you have a doc.phones into values? (could you give me the {{#autoform }} definition you have on your template ?

Comment: `{{#autoForm meteormethod="upsertOffice" id="officeForm" type="method" schema=Schemas.newOffice tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade"}}`

Comment: Great thanks!!! It's solved. I added 'doc=this' into {{#autoform }} definition and it now works.